# Why my Ubuntu's Internet will drop randomly?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

From last month, my Ubuntu 18.04 begin to drop internet randomly, I had changed the cable and unuseful. I don't know how long it will happen, maybe several days or hours.
This is the log:

```
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568002196.7542] connectivity: (eno1) timed out
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via systemd: servicename='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:09:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568002467.7598] connectivity: (eno1) response shorter than expected 'NetworkManager is online '; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.n m-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:14:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:14:28 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568002468.1303] connectivity: (wlx74da38f4306d) response did not match expected response 'Net workManager is online'; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:16:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 5 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0) ]
Sep  9 12:17:01 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR CRON[2668]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep  9 12:17:10 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:19:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 10 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)]
Sep  9 12:19:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568002767.7711] connectivity: (wlx74da38f4306d) response did not match expected response 'Net workManager is online'; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:19:45 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:19:53 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568002796.7539] connectivity: (eno1) timed out
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.n m-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:19:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:20:01 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:24:25 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 20 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0 )]
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003067.7583] connectivity: (eno1) response shorter than expected 'NetworkManager is online '; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.n m-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:24:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:24:28 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003068.0648] connectivity: (wlx74da38f4306d) response did not match expected response 'Net workManager is online'; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:24:39 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:26:28 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 9 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 166.111.152.1 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0) ]
Sep  9 12:26:46 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:29:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 11 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)]
Sep  9 12:29:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003367.7934] connectivity: (wlx74da38f4306d) response did not match expected response 'Net workManager is online'; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:29:28 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:29:39 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003396.7560] connectivity: (eno1) timed out
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.n m-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:29:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:31:25 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 6 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec 0)]
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[22238]: PRC: Renewing lease on eno1.
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[22238]: XMT: Renew on eno1, interval 9540ms.
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[22238]: RCV: Reply message on eno1 from fe80::3e61:4ff:fe44:e9f6.
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[22238]: IA_NA status code Success.
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8744] dhcp6 (eno1):   valid_lft 7500
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8745] dhcp6 (eno1):   preferred_lft 7200
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8745] dhcp6 (eno1):   address 2402:f000:4:33:808::bb2
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8745] dhcp6 (eno1):   nameserver '2402:f000:1:801::8:28'
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8745] dhcp6 (eno1):   nameserver '2402:f000:1:801::8:29'
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8746] dhcp (eno1):   domain search 'tsinghua.edu.cn.'
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003491.8746] dhcp6 (eno1): state changed bound -> bound, event ID="6b:81:63:7c|1568003491"Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via sy stemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.n m-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [eno1]: new request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:31:31 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp6-change' [eno1]: start running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:31:46 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec0)
Sep  9 12:33:07 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772257.104657] RTW: rtl8822b_c2h_handler_no_io: C2H, ID=12 seq=32 len=32
Sep  9 12:34:10 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[26148]: message repeated 9 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.239 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x636e1ec 0)]
Sep  9 12:34:15 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR avahi-daemon[1273]: Withdrawing address record for 166.111.154.239 on eno1.
Sep  9 12:34:15 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR avahi-daemon[1273]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 166.111.154.239.
Sep  9 12:34:15 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR avahi-daemon[1273]: Interface eno1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep  9 12:34:15 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003655.9355] policy: set 'Tsinghua-IPv4 1' (wlx74da38f4306d) as default for IPv4 routing a nd DNS
Sep  9 12:34:15 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gsd-sharing[2444]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded .
Sep  9 12:34:15 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gsd-sharing[2444]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.ser vice not loaded.
Sep  9 12:34:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003656.1671] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed bound -> expire
Sep  9 12:34:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003656.1995] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 26148
Sep  9 12:34:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003656.1996] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed expire -> done
Sep  9 12:34:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003656.1999] device (eno1): scheduling DHCPv4 restart in 120 seconds, 3 tries left (reason : lease expired)
Sep  9 12:34:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772327.257157] RTW: rtl8822b_c2h_handler_no_io: C2H, ID=12 seq=33 len=32
Sep  9 12:34:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772327.568424] RTW: traffic_status_watchdog(wlx74da38f4306d) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:22,rx_unicast:11)
Sep  9 12:34:21 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772331.600444] RTW: traffic_status_watchdog(wlx74da38f4306d) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:13,rx_unicast:8)
Sep  9 12:34:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772337.648454] RTW: traffic_status_watchdog(wlx74da38f4306d) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:14,rx_unicast:9)
Sep  9 12:34:27 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003667.7673] connectivity: (wlx74da38f4306d) response did not match expected response 'Net workManager is online'; assuming captive portal.
Sep  9 12:34:51 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gnome-shell[1697]: clutter-actor.c:10063: Act or 'StScrollBar' tried to allocate a size of -13.00 x 14.00
Sep  9 12:34:51 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gnome-shell[1697]: clutter-actor.c:10063: Act or 'StBoxLayout' tried to allocate a size of -13.00 x 1.00
Sep  9 12:34:51 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772361.840591] RTW: traffic_status_ watchdog(wlx74da38f4306d) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:11,rx_unicast:8)
Sep  9 12:34:53 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772363.856573] RTW: traffic_status_ watchdog(wlx74da38f4306d) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:11,rx_unicast:7)
Sep  9 12:34:56 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003696.756 1] connectivity: (eno1) timed out
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 100 3...
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Stopped target Default.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Stopped target Basic System.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Stopped target Paths.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Stopped Pending report trigge r for Ubuntu Report.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Stopped target Timers.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Stopped target Sockets.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Closed GnuPG network certific ate management daemon.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent and passphrase cache.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent (ssh-agent emulation).
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus  Socket.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Reached target Shutdown.
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Starting Exit the Session...
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27245]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID  5995 (kill).
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1003 .
Sep  9 12:35:58 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of jsbyy sheng.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 100 7...
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Stopped target Default.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Stopped target Basic System.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Stopped target Paths.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Stopped Pending report trigge r for Ubuntu Report.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Stopped target Sockets.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Closed GnuPG network certific ate management daemon.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent and passphrase cache.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus  Socket.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Stopped target Timers.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent (ssh-agent emulation).
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic ag ent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Reached target Shutdown.
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Starting Exit the Session...
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[27098]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID  5998 (kill).
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1007 .
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of klyjm .
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gnome-shell[1697]: clutter-actor.c:10063: Act or 'StScrollBar' tried to allocate a size of -13.00 x 14.00
Sep  9 12:35:59 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gnome-shell[1697]: clutter-actor.c:10063: Act or 'StBoxLayout' tried to allocate a size of -13.00 x 1.00
Sep  9 12:36:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003776.758 6] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep  9 12:36:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003776.761 7] dhcp4 (eno1): dhclient started with pid 6000
Sep  9 12:36:16 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[6000]: DHCPDISCOVER on eno1 to 255.2 55.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xf1c95c04)
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[6000]: DHCPREQUEST of 166.111.154.23 9 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x45cc9f1)
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[6000]: DHCPOFFER of 166.111.154.239  from 166.111.152.1
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[6000]: DHCPACK of 166.111.154.239 fr om 166.111.152.1
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.873 9] dhcp4 (eno1):   address 166.111.154.239
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.873 9] dhcp4 (eno1):   plen 22 (255.255.252.0)
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.873 9] dhcp4 (eno1):   gateway 166.111.152.1
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR avahi-daemon[1273]: Joining mDNS multicast gr oup on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 166.111.154.239.
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.874 0] dhcp4 (eno1):   lease time 3600
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.874 0] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '166.111.8.28'
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.874 0] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '166.111.8.29'
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.874 0] dhcp4 (eno1):   domain name 'tsinghua.edu.cn'
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.874 0] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR avahi-daemon[1273]: New relevant interface en o1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR avahi-daemon[1273]: Registering new address r ecord for 166.111.154.239 on eno1.IPv4.
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1568003777.876 8] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Activating via sy stemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.n m-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=1248 comm="/usr/sbin/Networ kManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script D ispatcher Service...
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gsd-sharing[2444]: Failed to StopUnit service : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded .
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dhclient[6000]: bound to 166.111.154.239 -- r enewal in 1464 seconds.
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gsd-sharing[2444]: Failed to StopUnit service : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.ser vice not loaded.
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR dbus-daemon[1243]: [system] Successfully acti vated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Di spatcher Service.
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eno1]: n ew request (1 scripts)
Sep  9 12:36:17 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eno1]: s tart running ordered scripts...
Sep  9 12:36:18 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR kernel: [5772448.528996] RTW: traffic_status_ watchdog(wlx74da38f4306d) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:13,rx_unicast:9)
Sep  9 12:36:55 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR colord[1353]: failed to get session [pid 9928 ]: No data available
Sep  9 12:37:02 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR colord[1353]: failed to get session [pid 9928 ]: No data available
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of klyjm .
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 100 7...
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started Session 3342 of user klyj m.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Listening on GnuPG cryptograph ic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Listening on GnuPG network cer tificate management daemon.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bu s Socket.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Listening on GnuPG cryptograph ic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Started Pending report trigger  for Ubuntu Report.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Reached target Paths.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Listening on GnuPG cryptograph ic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Listening on GnuPG cryptograph ic agent and passphrase cache.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Reached target Timers.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Listening on D-Bus User Messag e Bus Socket.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Reached target Sockets.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Reached target Basic System.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Reached target Default.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[6043]: Startup finished in 55ms.
Sep  9 12:37:03 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1007 .
Sep  9 12:37:04 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gnome-shell[1697]: clutter-actor.c:10063: Act or 'StScrollBar' tried to allocate a size of -13.00 x 14.00
Sep  9 12:37:04 C249-SYS-7048GR-TR gnome-shell[1697]: clutter-actor.c:10063: Act or 'StBoxLayout' tried to allocate a size of -13.00 x 1.00
```

This is the lshw:

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:81:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 01
       serial: ac:1f:6b:81:63:7c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa ip=166.111.154.239 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:31 memory:fb020000-fb03ffff ioport:f020(size=32) memory:fb044000-fb047fff memory:384000000000-38400001ffff memory:384000020000-38400003ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:81:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 01
       serial: ac:1f:6b:81:63:7d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:47 memory:fb000000-fb01ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:fb040000-fb043fff memory:384000040000-38400005ffff memory:384000060000-38400007ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx74da38f4306d
       serial: 74:da:38:f4:30:6d
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8822bu ip=183.173.88.156 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

This is the reslove:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search tsinghua.edu.cn
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing in the info you provided it appears that the problem is that your connection is being dropped upstream.  In this case, by something in the networking infrastructure at Tsinghua University in Beijing, China.

Of course the NIC cable, networking hardware or something in the data closet could be the culprit.  I see no evidence that Ubuntu is causing this failure though.